# Input type file hidden click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to use the following query to modify this upload button.

HTML:

```
 <input type="file" name="something" id="myfileid" style="display:none;">
```

I tried to use an image to replace the `<input type="file">` "button".

```
 <img src="some/thing/url/here" onclick="$('myfileid').click();">
```

As you can see, here I am using ajax to redirect the click on image to file. Though it seems as if it doesn't work in the major browsers like Safari.
Another Side Note: I have already added this code to many pages on my website already, so is there a simple solution in which I only have to add some Javascript? Thanks.

Comment: does it have to be javascript?

Comment: [Correct Answer Currently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34690084/9712543) It looks like the correct answer depends on JQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src="some/thing/url/here" onclick="$('#myfileid').trigger('click'); return true;">
```

Comment: works in my mac but not sure how will work on windows safari and other old browsers

Comment: Provide your link.
So I can check it in Ubuntu.

Comment: its is on local environment and on live it is session protected .... should i test on codepen?

Comment: Yes otherwise make jsfiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100207/discussion-between-ali-and-sonam-sharma).

Answer (score 9):

If it doesn't have to be solved in javascript, you can easily achieve this by wrapping the image within a `label for="myfileid"`, just like this

**[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/bdarmarq/1/)**

```html
<label for="myfileid">
  <img src="//ninjaforms.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/2012/10/file-uploads1.png" width="250">
</label>
<input type="file" name="something" id="myfileid" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: How do I get the file object?

Comment: @chovy via the `onChange` handler in the file input object.